# Delete copied version of /proc folder in unix

Tags: permissions, proc

I accidentally copied the files from /proc to one of the directory under /home

But now I am not able to delete those copied contents. It says "Permission denied". Folder size is ~300GB

How can I safely delete the copied version of proc folder?

Comment: As an aside, please specify your OS exactly, not "unix". Not all Unix-like systems have /proc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How to delete files "safely"
2. How to solve your "Permission denied" problem

### 1. How to delete files "safely"

Modern versions of GNU `rm` will keep you safe from accidentally deleting all of `/` , but you can still accidentally delete all of `/home`...  The safest way I can think is to first `cd` into the directory, use `ls` to check it is the right one, then delete its contents, then `cd ..` and `rmdir proc`.  `rmdir` is very safe because it only deletes empty directories.

*To delete everything in the current directory*, use `rm -r -- *`

It is probably "safe" to forget the `--` in the `rm` command.  However it might not work as expected, for example if there is a file called `-i`.

You could use a graphical file manager instead, which is generally safer than `rm`.  You can move the file(s) to the "trash".  This will leave you a chance to undo the action, until you empty the whole trash, or delete the file(s) from the trash.  I prefer using this when possible.  It does not always work well. I managed to crash Gnome Files while testing this :-).

### 2. How to solve your "Permission denied" problem

Your problem is that some of the subdirectories have been marked as "read only". (And you are not running as `root`, which ignores these markings).

You can allow writes to the current directory and everything inside it, using `chmod u+w -R .`  Then you will be able to delete it.

In some cases, using a graphical file manager to delete a folder will change the permissions for you automatically.  Or, you can use the file manager to change permissions manually.  If you use Gnome Files: right click -> Properties -> Permissions.  Next to Owner, set "Create and delete files".  Then do the same again under "Change permission for enclosed files".

Comment: it worked... this was life saver...thanks :)